# Error trying to open VeraCrypt container, veracrypt::process::execute:108

Tags: software-installation, veracrypt

On Ubuntu 16.04 a machine I've installed VeraCrypt 1.19. When I'm trying to open an existing container I get the error:

"No such file or directory: dmsetup"

```
veracrypt::process::execute:108
```

I created it on Windows 10 on a NTFS partition - but I don't think that's the problem.

I've tried the `sudo apt-get install dmsetup` thing, but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/886785/edit) your quesiton and add what you mean by "doesn't work". Can you give us the precise error message?

Comment: After the dmsetup install, (1) I open VeraCrypt, (2) select a slot (drive in Win), (3) select the file container in NTFS partition, then hit MOUNT button. It just comes back with the same error.

Comment: This [comment](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/encrypt-data-in-linux-with-veracrypt-an-alternative-to-truecrypt#comment-3155982691) says to execute: `sudo apt install exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils dmsetup` Does that help?

Answer (score 5):

I did

```
 sudo apt-get install dmsetup
```

according to [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321663&s=56d4e2ab6d8b540aabf91b1f340edcc2&p=13475805#post13475805). It started working after that.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and solved it. What I do is checking the "Do not use kernel cryptographic services" then it works.

go through with :veraCrypt >> Settings >> Default keyfiles > Tab-[System Integration]

[System Integration] > Kernel Services : "Do not use kernel cryptographic services" (<--- check it)

Good luck!

Comment: Works. But there is a warning `Disabling the use of kernel cryptographic services can degrade performance.`